# Differential equations why doesnt this work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve the equation $tx'=x+\tan\frac xt$. It is homogeneous. I wrote $x=u\cdot t$ and I have $x'=\frac{x+\tan\frac xt}t$ and then $x'=\frac{ut+\tan\frac{ut}t}t$ in the end I get $x'=u+\frac{\tan u}t$. So $u't +u=u +\frac{\tan u}t$. So $u'=\frac{\tan u}{t^2}$, 
$\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dt}=\frac{\tan u}{t^2}$. $\int\frac{\mathrm d u}{\tan u}=\int\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^2}$, so $\ln|\sin u|=-\frac1t$, but the answer in my book is 
$\sin\frac xt=\frac t2$. How come?

Comment: Does $tg$ mean tangent, by any chance?

Comment: yes,im sorry it means tangent :)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is correct, except you should have  $-\frac{1}{t}+C$ after integration. Either your textbook has a wrong answer or you looked up the answer to a wrong problem.

I double-checked with Maple: it said  $\sin(x/t)=Ce^{-1/t}$.